# Export CSV file from SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can we set it up to export directly from SQL Server to a CSV file and schedule that daily?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use DTS wizard or SSIS or write your own exporter

Comment: This is the correct answer. Old-school, you'd use BCP but it's not great. SSIS is a huge improvement.